# Fix all issues or warnings in resharper at one step in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Is there any way to fix all issues or warnings at one step , better than fixing each issue alone ????

Comment: How in Cthulu's name is it meant to do that? Even if you took a simple one like splleing mistake, Splleing might be a piece of acceptable jargon. What if said variable name spelled correctly was also in scope at the same time as the "wrong" one? Are they same or not, should it then take the declaration out, what does that do to your scoping. If you want to cut down the amount of problems tool like resharper discovers, stop writng code it doesn't like.

Comment: If you do a full cleanup Ctrl E-C the R# will fix as much as it can, but not everything.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for that is `CTRL+ALT+F`

See [this link](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html) for the presentation of the shortcut and what you can do with it.

Comment: I think you mean CTRL+E, CTRL+C